# Placeholder text inside comment can not clear on website

Tags: discussion, bug

Yesterday I opened the Stack Exchange site from my [Lumia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_Lumia_800) phone, and when I click on `Add Comment` and tap on comment Box, the placeholder text is written in the comment. It is not cleared, so may be it's a bug on the website.

**Browser:** Opera Mini.

**Version:** 9.1.0.232.

Please kindly test it, and remove the bug.

Comment: [Opera Mini is not supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177352/unable-to-start-a-bounty-using-opera-mini/177509#177509). Why don't you use IE or Edge?